# Ways to measure deviation from a discrete uniform distribution

Tags: gini, diversity, discrete-distributions

I'm looking for a way to characterize the deviation from a discrete uniform distribution.

Example: 50 balls are distributed over 10 urns.

In the most equal case, all urns get 5 balls.
In the most unequal case, one urn gets all balls.
Is there a (scalar) statistic that measures how equal things are distributed?

I thinking of something like the Gini index, but that does not quite fit in this scenario.

Comment: Why not just use the standard deviation?

Comment: The discrete uniform maximizes entropy, so you can use entropy --- more generally, in ecology and other disiplines such measures are called measures of (bio)-diversity, there are many posts on this site!

Comment: @cosine Start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index